# Padding at top of fo:table-row

Tags: xsl-fo, apache-fop, xslt-3.0

I'm using Apache FOP v2.9, with Saxon HE v12.3 & XSLT Version 3.0 under JDK v17.

I'm trying to specify Padding at the Row level of a Table.

According to the docs this should work, but the Padding is being ignored:

I use Data2Type's reference, as its easy to understand & normally very accurate, but in this case obviously not:
https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/attribute/padding-top

(I'm afraid their Reference is only available in German)

```
<xsl:template match="OrderLines">
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border="solid 1pt">
        <fo:table-column column-width="18mm"/>
        <fo:table-column/>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="OrderLine">
                <fo:table-row         padding-top="15pt">
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>SKU</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell>
                        <fo:block>Qty</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

This works fine:

```
<xsl:template match="OrderLines">
    <fo:table table-layout="fixed" width="100%" border="solid 1pt">
        <fo:table-column column-width="18mm"/>
        <fo:table-column/>
        <fo:table-body>
            <xsl:for-each select="OrderLine">
                <fo:table-row>
                    <fo:table-cell         padding-top="15pt">
                        <fo:block>SKU</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                    <fo:table-cell         padding-top="15pt">
                        <fo:block>Qty</fo:block>
                    </fo:table-cell>
                </fo:table-row>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </fo:table-body>
    </fo:table>
</xsl:template>
```

Any ideas, anyone?

The generated FO (excerpt) looks like this:

```
<fo:table-row padding-top="15pt">
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>SKU</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-cell>
        <fo:block>Qty</fo:block>
    </fo:table-cell>
</fo:table-row>
```

Comment: Is Saxon or XSLT decisive to reproduce that? Or does it happen with Apache FOP with static XSL-FO as well?

Comment: Ok, I've checked out the generated FO & appended that to my original posting.

Comment: ...also I've generated the PDF from that FO without Saxon (but still using Apache FOP, as that's the only engine I've got). The "<fo:table-row padding-top="15pt">" is still being ignored.

Comment: Does FOP emit any messages/warnings that it has encountered unknown or unsupported elements and/or attributes?

Comment: What effect are you trying to achieve that requires the padding?

Comment: .> According to the docs this should work ... please point us to those "docs" because they are incorrect.

Comment: I've added a URL (only available in German) to the FO "Reference" I used. https://www.data2type.de/xml-xslt-xslfo/xsl-fo/xslfo-referenz/attribute/padding-top

Comment: They, like some of the rest of us, probably generated that list of FOs from the XML source for the XSL 1.1 recommendation. You've made me realise that the **focheck** schema and framework for XSL-FO (see https://github.com/AntennaHouse/focheck) has the same bug, so thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`padding-top` and other padding properties do not apply to `fo:table-row`.

The definition of `fo:table-row` at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#fo_table-row does list the "Common Border, Padding, and Background Properties" as applying to `fo:table-row`, but that's immediately followed by a note stating that only the background properties apply, plus the border properties if `border-collapse` on the `fo:table` is `collapse` or `collapse-with-precedence`.  There's no allowance for the padding properties.

`fo:table-row` isn't listed with `padding-top` in the "Properties and the FOs they apply to" appendix section at https://www.w3.org/TR/xsl11/#prapply